# Mongodb subdocument array lookup to subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongo. i have following collections.

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb256c9e519051af2eeb5f7"),
    "name" : "Income",
    "types" : [ 
        {
            "typeId" : ObjectId("5eb257a3e519051af2eeb624"),
            "name" : "W2",
            "tenantId" : null,
            "message" : "",
            "createdOn" : null,
            "createdBy" : 1.0,
            "isActive" : true
        }, 
        {
            "typeId" : ObjectId("5eb257a3e519051af2eeb639"),
            "name" : "Salary Slip",
            "tenantId" : 1,
            "message" : "",
            "createdOn" : null,
            "createdBy" : 1.0,
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Request:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb25d1fe519051af2eeb72d"),
    "employeeId" : 1234,
    "customerId" : 1275,
    "tenantId" : 1,
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "loanApplicationId" : 1.0,
    "status" : "requested",
    "message" : "Dear John, please send following documents.",
    "documents" : [ 
        {
            "typeId" : null,
            "displayName" : "W2 2016",
            "message" : "please upload salary slip for year 2016",
            "status" : "requested",
            "files" : []
        }, 
        {
            "typeId" : ObjectId("5eb257a3e519051af2eeb624"),
            "displayName" : "W2 2016",
            "message" : "please upload salary slip for year 2016",
            "status" : "requested",
            "files" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

typeId in the document collection is the id for the document type where typeId in the request is the foreign field that can be nullable as well. how can i get the below output.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb25d1fe519051af2eeb72d"),
    "employeeId" : 1234,
    "customerId" : 1275,
    "tenantId" : 1,
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "loanApplicationId" : 1.0,
    "status" : "requested",
    "message" : "Dear John, please send following documents.",
    "documents" : [ 
        {
            "typeId" : null,
            "typeInfo": null,
            "displayName" : "W2 2016",
            "message" : "please upload salary slip for year 2016",
            "status" : "requested",
            "files" : []
        }, 
        {
            "typeId" : ObjectId("5eb257a3e519051af2eeb624"),
            "typeInfo": {
            "name": "W2" 
            },
            "displayName" : "W2 2016",
            "message" : "please upload salary slip for year 2016",
            "status" : "requested",
            "files" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loved to solve this problem, it was a tricky, long and complex. Well, I am also a beginner, so I used all the basic concepts. You can try the below code:

```js
db.request.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$documents"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "document",
      let: {
        req_typeId: "$documents.typeId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$types"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$req_typeId",
                "$types.typeId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "documents.example"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$documents.example",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      employeeId: {
        $first: "$employeeId"
      },
      customerId: {
        $first: "$customerId"
      },
      tenantId: {
        $first: "$tenantId"
      },
      createdOn: {
        $first: "$createdOn"
      },
      loanApplicationId: {
        $first: "$loanApplicationId"
      },
      status: {
        $first: "$status"
      },
      message: {
        $first: "$message"
      },
      documents: {
        $push: {
          typeId: "$documents.typeId",
          typeInfo: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$documents.example",
                  undefined
                ]
              },
              null,
              {
                name: "$documents.example.types.name"
              }
            ]
          },
          displayName: "$documents.displayName",
          message: "$documents.message",
          status: "$documents.status",
          files: "$documents.files"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you get stuck at any point, I have provided [MongoPlayGround Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sp3v4Oh_STb), here you can execute the query stage by stage of the aggregation pipeline, else reach out for me. It's a long query, it will take time to understand. At the same time, I will be trying to shrink it. If I get anything, I will update it here.

**Edits:**

I have shortened the query by almost 50% (in terms of lines). Here is my previous approach's [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NcZEzwZKNRh)

Answer (score 0):

With the default `$lookup` syntax, you can join with atomic / array values and store the result inside `tmp` variable. In the next step, we iterate over `documents` field and find within `tmp` variable items with the same `typeId`.

**Note:** If you need more fields than `name`, just change to `{typeInfo: "$$this"}`.

Try this one:

```
db.Requests.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Documents",
      localField: "documents.typeId",
      foreignField: "types.typeId",
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: "$$REMOVE",
      documents: {
        $map: {
          input: "$documents",
          as: "doc",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$doc",
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: "$tmp.types",
                      initialValue: [],
                      in: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                          "$$value",
                          "$$this"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  initialValue: {},
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.typeId",
                          "$$doc.typeId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        typeInfo: {
                          name: "$$this.name"
                        }
                      },
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O2tj2GWEwu4)